# Drawing chart with lots of points efficiently on iOS

Tags: ios, graph, plot, drawing, core-graphics

I'm looking for a way to draw a line chart with lots of points (up to 10 000) efficiently on iOS. The graph gets real-time data and needs to be updated multiple times a second. I'm trying to figure out a way to draw the graph efficiently so it doesn't max out the CPU and block the main thread while drawing.

I'm currently creating a `UIBezierPath` for the line chart, in a background thread, adding all the points and drawing it in a CALayer (that has asynchronous drawing enabled). It's not very quick, maxes out the CPU and the drawing is so slow the UI becomes laggy. I am plotting real time data, and in theory I could reuse the same `UIBezierPath` every time and just append the new points, however older values are discarded after a while, meaning the points for the deleted values would have to be removed from the bezier path, which isn't possible.

I haven't found anything on efficient plotting large data sets on iOS, but I'm hoping there are ways to use the GPU to increase the performance.

Comment: do you have to draw all 10k points? Even on an iPad screen, that seems overly excessive... (more points than horizontal pixels). Have you considered averaging out the data into a smaller set?

Comment: @originaluser2 I totally agree. I'm doing some client work and haven't yet been able to talk them out of the idea of drawing these many points.

Comment: well if you are able to convince them, averaging is your best bet! I doubt you'll be able to leverage much of GPU without going full into Metal/Open GL. I'm pretty sure `UIBezierPath` mainly uses Core Graphics under the hood, and that all runs on the CPU.

Comment: SciChart iOS supports over 10k points easily (tested with up to 1M points). Version 2.3 will support Metal as well as OpenGLES for the simulator https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-performance-comparison/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an implementation for drawing a graph with OpenGL: https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/blob/master/EZAudio/EZAudioPlotGL.m

It's actually pretty easy and the performance improvements are huge.

For devices with the A7 chip (or newer) it would probably be even faster to draw the graph with metal, which should also be pretty easy. There are a few guides on how to do so: https://www.raywenderlich.com/77488/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation like this a few years ago (back in iPhone 4 days).

I used a `CGMutablePathRef` to which I added points using `CGPathMoveToPoint` for the first point, and `CGPathAddLineToPoint` for subsequent points.

To get acceptable performance, I stored the data points in a C array (not an `NSArray`). Also, when plotting a point, if its display coordinates were the same as the last plotted point, I just skipped the call to `CGPathAddLineToPoint`. (This will often be the case when you have more data points than pixels).

I don't recall the exact drawing time, but it was surprisingly fast.

Comment: if you're unable to average down the data set, then this is definitely the next best option. (without going full Metal)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than plotting points using `UIBezierPath`, you could set up a `CGBitmapContext` and then plot the points "by hand", e.g.

```
color = (0xFF << 24) | (blue << 16) | (green << 8) | (red); // AABBGGRR
for (loop = 0; loop < count; loop++)
{
    index = indices[loop];
    self.pixels[index] = color;
}
```

where self.pixels is the buffer you used to create the CGBitmapContext.  Then, in drawRect:

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(self.imageContext);
CGContextDrawImage(c, self.bounds, image);
CGImageRelease(image);
```

I think you'll find this to be significantly faster (and smaller) than using CGPath or UIBezierPath.